# Error when calling theme Props in component using ReactJs and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I need to pass the color of a theme to a component, I'm using type script (I'm a beginner).

I came across an error that I can't solve.

The error is: **Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)**

and it appears in the color line of my code

```js
<Linkxx
 color={(props) => props.theme.colors.red}
 size={11}
 weight={500}
 decoration={false}
/>
```

My component

```js
import React from 'react';

import { Container } from './styles';

interface LinkProps {
  color: string;
  size?: number;
  weight?: number;
  decoration?: boolean;
}

const Link: React.FC<LinkProps> = ({ color, size, weight, decoration }) => {
  return (
    <Container
      decoration={decoration}
      weight={weight}
      size={size}
      color={color}
      to="/teste"
    >
      teste
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Link;
```

The code where the problem occurs

```js
import React from 'react';

import Header from '../../components/Header';
import Linkxx from '../../components/Link';

import {
  Container,
  Content,
  UserCard,
  Avatar,
  UserData,
  Canais,
  BoxAction,
} from './styles';

const User: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Container>
        <Content>
          <h1>User</h1>
          <UserCard>
            <Avatar />
            <UserData>
              <span>Sample Name</span>
              <small>sample@gmail.com</small>
            </UserData>
            <Canais>
              <span>Adm, Manager</span>
              <div>
                <small>test</small>
                <small>test</small>
                <small>test</small>
              </div>
            </Canais>
            <BoxAction>
              <div>
                <Linkxx
                  color={(props) => props.theme.colors.red}
                  size={11}
                  weight={500}
                  decoration={false}
                />
              </div>
            </BoxAction>
          </UserCard>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};

export default User;
```

How can I use the theme properties when calling my component?

Comment: interface `LinkProps` has `color` props defined as string but you are passing it a function.

Comment: But I am passing a function that returns a string, I will try to change the typing.

Comment: `(x: PropsType) => string` might be used as a type.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Linkxx
  // color={(props) => props.theme.colors.red} // You passed a function
  color={props.theme.colors.red} // Try passing a value or string i.e. props.theme.colors.red
  size={11}
  weight={500}
  decoration={false}
/>
```

As your interface says `color` is string:

```
interface LinkProps {
  color: string;  // color is string
  size?: number;
  weight?: number;
  decoration?: boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the type '**any**' to your '**props**' parameter as such:

```
color={(props: any) => props.theme.colors.red}
size={11}
weight={500}
decoration={false}
```

Because in typescript you need to specify the type of **props** you are going to send or it takes the default type defined. if you don't want to specify any type then **explicitly** ask the component to expect state and props of ‘**any**’ type. Refer to this article for detailed solution: [React/typescript: Parameter ‘props’ implicitly has an ‘any’ type error](https://medium.com/codespace69/react-typescript-parameter-props-implicitly-has-an-any-type-error-653f224f6b9d)